# How to display the text on clicking the mouse?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have added event Mouse Click and written a method

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x = e.X;
    int y = e.Y;
    TextBox TextWithNumber = new TextBox();
    TextWithNumber.Width = 100;
    TextWithNumber.Height = 100;
    TextWithNumber.Location = new Point(x, y);
    TextWithNumber.Text = "TEXT";
    TextWithNumber.BackColor = Color.Green;
    TextWithNumber.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

But the text doesn't appear. Tell me, please, what have I done wrong?

EDITED: Correct answer: the line Controls.Add(TextWithNumber); should be added to the end of the method.

Comment: you do realise that this code will create (and with the given answer add) a NEW textbox EVERY time you click the button, are you sure you want to do that? why not change the value of an existing button?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the new textbox to the form:

```
Controls.Add(TextWithNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `Parent` - the control you place `TextBox` on:

```
...

TextBox TextWithNumber = new TextBox() {
  Parent    = this,            // Put Text Box on "this" - i.e. on the form
  Width     = 100,
  Height    = 100,
  Location  = new Point(e.X, e.Y),
  Text      = "TEXT",
  BackColor = Color.Green,
  ForeColor = Color.Red,
};

...
```